# jQuery ajax xml response stripped xml tags

Tags: ajax, xml

The server returns this XML:

```
<Person>
  <FirstName>John</FirstName>
  <LastName>Buttler</LastName>
  <Age>49</Age>
</Person>
```

In this ajax method

```
function SetContent(selectedVal) {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Home/GetTestRecordContent",
        data: { testRecordId: selectedVal },
        dataType: 'xml',
    }).done(function (result) {
        if (result) {
            $(result).each(function () {
                $("#TestRecordContent").text($(this).text());
            });
        };
    })
```

I only receive text without XML tags:

```
John
Buttler
49
```

How do I get the complete XML document with all XML tags ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As BDeliers said, set the type to text (or just remove the datatype option, and leave it to default) and it should work as you want it.

Also make sure you don't use $(this).text(), but simply 'result' in your jquery call :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Home/GetTestRecordContent",
    data: { testRecordId: selectedVal }
}).done(function (result) {
  $("#TestRecordContent").text(result);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just set the datatype as text in your request, it will return you your XML with all the tags

Comment: Setting datatype to 'text' did not help, still missing XML tags.